# Why does Gmail add spacings in the emails I send?

Tags: gmail

Quite often, I compose an email in Gmail, I send the email, and than realize that some weird spacings had appeared in the email that I just sent. How to avoid that,  without resorting to switching to plain text?

Example:

[image]

became

[image]

when I sent it.

Comment: Are you writing it in the compose box yourself or copy-pasting it from somewhere else?

Comment: @DeepakKamat In that case I simply edited a forwarded email.

Comment: This is just an educated guest, but from what I’ve seen, these are usually carriage return or end of line characters that are interpreted differently. I don’t think you can fix this without resorting to switching to plain text.

Answer (score 1):

If you are pasting the text from elsewhere instead of manually writing it in the compose window, there's a chance that you are also copying hidden characters that create those spacings.

I suggest you to recreate the case by composing a mail the same way and then try to compose it again but instead of pasting the text, just write it manually on the compose window. If the latter works without issue, then the problem is those hidden characters.